# Output certain string in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, printing, output, special-characters

I'm doing this exercise:

> Write a program to get a number N and a sequence of numbers and characters. As a result the program must output first all numbers and then the symbols. All members must be separated by space.

So I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 1000;
    char a[N];
    
    size_t n = 0;
    
    cin >> n;
    
    if ( N < n ) n = N;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    
    auto it = stable_partition( a, a + n, []( unsigned char c ){ return ::isdigit( c ); } );
    stable_partition( it, a + n, []( unsigned char c ){ return ::isalpha( c ); } );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now when the program gets following input:

> 1000 < h X " O d ? 3 s P ? ^ ; p l | ^ ^ ) I & B " 2 h h v a a r M N 2 Q 2 a ! a ) N T s $ J [ Y X , 7 | = + m - f $ ] h c 0 x A 8 l d x m + C + y Z 9 U d E Y b = 6 ^ n ] y P 1 @ Y ^ . U 1 e 1 3 w U d y E / M i L 1 T B Y . 7 t ' . o g g . ` ' & k @ [ R % t O - \ # Y [ T k V ' H t L H I C _ t . K S l t y @ B + - " U Z 4 B M l C 0 L ^ ] v c 0 B z K P . ~ i } y ^ q C V [ c 5 Y U L % N V - 8 < a [ y [ P J ) k Q I ` ~ q z d ) Y / Q b M [ h E 7 f { V S ( F K ` ? 4 ? _ C - + O X 6 n V a & $ p w C C D U 3 B y w : s M < z A D | 7 Q ? i & 4 9 > ! + e E [ @ ; i b } $ @ E L d ` w B 1 ~ N ; s x B 6 p W 7 g m o = _ 7 B C ' i 3 & Y r G 3 j g a Z j . ^ z ^ U . 1 7 > t [ o - G " b ~ ` ( h : R ~ R ~ F E l Q S 0 J j F ^ x 4 u K y 4 F | X C ~ B ? O r + } | " j A C % w ? v w | S E = c 4 6 . @ H e q D a & 1 c % P | B " } g 0 9 | 7 n . # B 7 7 ` H v Q I i B g r r Q ; Q 5 c , ` C y x ( J m 1 W h @ 6 I a X _ g l 9 j l # 8 > d < E ^ O { 2 _ l 8 u f L _ _ P F w > i ( x 5 4 f X 1 b 9 v S p I < V q 0 [ E I P j > ' $ h Q , I 5 7 R 5 I T T ; I R 4 V E ~ . Q " @ n s u & 0 8 f 6 G U n ] 8 q u 6 7 j 2 T ! p ' " J ! t 5 E - E c ] r 2 : T ^ T j X V k 2 k [ z P R / m , / M ; I 5 d ( & b ^ Z m Z T " Q m t A a E d _ } j R H S [ o g | - ! F " $ J L E } J C b Z C a # & & r R T . " R o e V h / 9 t T < S ; l U 8 O q S _ Y t # L l 9 Y { { . o I Y G Y [ f Y \ K j S F ; r , O | 9 E 6 9 C T X p v G " ! ; M _ 3 K $ o $ . ] N q L > n = * M c a i x s J S v = @ l D : ' 0 { f e d 7 1 E J G \ K L { v n C T / h y G c Q N s C C \ = & ` , 5 6 g G . P 6 - r > F z L s b ( c [ J P { . o T a 7 a / ? h 4 6 ; W $ h c i m f x , D l _ 6 9 C % l a L r q ' F 1 m } 5 l c 0 ( V I [ V Y . 0 G H 1 e j K = n p p b 9 v h V ; x - / o z R 3 n ' ; L P W } 3 > y Z = 8 9 ' - | x u , 2 l z t } | > w k 8 | P 8 , g k U ` 8 F , < 8 g & z c ^ Z 0 s < \ ^ D { 3 | ! C H R y b 3 ` C q I g p 0 $ e S * k e < 8 < q & - 1 A X < b / a K q x q w ) b I ? T h - e ! A . z J p U l } * P G H ! m - F ' = a : B ~ ! . k 4 A " U / Y c 4 b t u } < U K X y 1 H A # { E 3

It forgets to output symbols like `` < ` " ``.

As result I get false output with "eaten" symbols.

My program executes:

> 3 2 2 2 7 0 8 9 6 1 1 1 3 1 7 4 0 0 5 8 7 4 6 3 7 4 9 1 6 7 7 3 3 1 7 0 4 4 4 6 1 0 9 7 7 7 5 1 6 9 8 2 8 5 4 1 9 0 5 7 5 4 0 8 6 8 6 7 2 5 2 2 5 9 8 9 9 6 9 3 0 7 1 5 6 6 7 4 6 6 9 1 5 0 0 1 9 3 3 8 9 2 8 8 8 8 0 3 3 0 8 1 4 4 1 3 h X O d s P p l I B h h v a a r M N Q a a N T s J Y X m f h c x A l d x m C y Z U d E Y b n y P Y U e w U d y E M i L T B Y t o g g k R t O Y T k V H t L H I C t K S l t y B U Z B M l C L v c B z K P i y q C V c Y U L N V a y P J k Q I q z d Y Q b M h E f V S F K C O X n V a p w C C D U B y w s M z A D Q i e E i b E L d w B N s x B p W g m o B C i Y r G j g a Z j z U t o G b h R R F E l Q S J j F x u K y F X C B O r j A C w v w S E c H e q D a c P B g n B H v Q I i B g r r Q Q c C y x J m W h I a X g l j l d E O l u f L P F w i x f X b v S p I V q E I P j h Q I R I T T I R V E Q n s u f G U n q u j T p J t E E c r T T j X V k k z P R m M I d b Z m Z T Q m t A a E d j R H S o g F J L E J C b Z C a r R T R o e V h t T S l U O q S Y t L l Y o I Y G Y f Y K j S F r O E C T X p v G M K o N q L n M c a i x s J S v l D f e d E J G K L v n C T h y G c Q N s C C g G P r F z L s b c J P o T a a h W h c i m f x D l C l a L r q F m l c V I V Y G H e j K n p p b v h V x o z R n L P W y Z x u l z t w k P g k U F g z c Z s D C H R y b C q I g p e S k e q A X b a K q x q w b I T h e A z J p U l P G H m F a B k A U Y c b t u U K X y H A E < " ? ? ^ ; | ^ ^ ) & " ! ) $ [ , | = + - $ ] + + = ^ ] @ ^ . / . ' . . ` ' & @ [ % - \ # [ ' _ . @ + - " ^ ] . ~ } ^ [ % - < [ [ ) ` ~ ) / [ { ( ` ? ? _ - + & $ : < | ? & > ! + [ @ ; } $ @ ` ~ ; = _ ' & . ^ ^ . > [ - " ~ ` ( : ~ ~ ^ | ~ ? + } | " % ? | = . @ & % | " } | . # ` ; , ` ( @ _ # > < ^ { _ _ _ > ( < [ > ' $ , ; ~ . " @ & ] ! ' " ! - ] : ^ [ / , / ; ( & ^ " _ } [ | - ! " $ } # & & . " / < ; _ # { { . [ \ ; , | " ! ; _ $ $ . ] > = * = @ : ' { \ { / \ = & ` , . - > ( [ { . / ? ; $ , _ % ' } ( [ . = ; - / ' ; } > = ' - | , } | > | , ` , < & ^ < \ ^ { | ! ` $ * < < & - < / ) ? - ! . } * ! - ' = : ~ ! . " / } < # {

Whereas the right answer is:

> 3 2 2 2 7 0 8 9 6 1 1 1 3 1 7 4 0 0 5 8 7 4 6 3 7 4 9 1 6 7 7 3 3 1 7 0 4 4 4 6 1 0 9 7 7 7 5 1 6 9 8 2 8 5 4 1 9 0 5 7 5 4 0 8 6 8 6 7 2 5 2 2 5 9 8 9 9 6 9 3 0 7 1 5 6 6 7 4 6 6 9 1 5 0 0 1 9 3 3 8 9 2 8 8 8 8 0 3 3 0 8 1 4 4 1 3 < h X " O d ? s P ? ^ ; p l | ^ ^ ) I & B " h h v a a r M N Q a ! a ) N T s $ J [ Y X , | = + m - f $ ] h c x A l d x m + C + y Z U d E Y b = ^ n ] y P @ Y ^ . U e w U d y E / M i L T B Y . t ' . o g g . ` ' & k @ [ R % t O - \ # Y [ T k V ' H t L H I C _ t . K S l t y @ B + - " U Z B M l C L ^ ] v c B z K P . ~ i } y ^ q C V [ c Y U L % N V - < a [ y [ P J ) k Q I ` ~ q z d ) Y / Q b M [ h E f { V S ( F K ` ? ? _ C - + O X n V a & $ p w C C D U B y w : s M < z A D | Q ? i & > ! + e E [ @ ; i b } $ @ E L d ` w B ~ N ; s x B p W g m o = _ B C ' i & Y r G j g a Z j . ^ z ^ U . > t [ o - G " b ~ ` ( h : R ~ R ~ F E l Q S J j F ^ x u K y F | X C ~ B ? O r + } | " j A C % w ? v w | S E = c . @ H e q D a & c % P | B " } g | n . # B ` H v Q I i B g r r Q ; Q c , ` C y x ( J m W h @ I a X _ g l j l # > d < E ^ O { _ l u f L _ _ P F w > i ( x f X b v S p I < V q [ E I P j > ' $ h Q , I R I T T ; I R V E ~ . Q " @ n s u & f G U n ] q u j T ! p ' " J ! t E - E c ] r : T ^ T j X V k k [ z P R / m , / M ; I d ( & b ^ Z m Z T " Q m t A a E d _ } j R H S [ o g | - ! F " $ J L E } J C b Z C a # & & r R T . " R o e V h / t T < S ; l U O q S _ Y t # L l Y { { . o I Y G Y [ f Y \ K j S F ; r , O | E C T X p v G " ! ; M _ K $ o $ . ] N q L > n = * M c a i x s J S v = @ l D : ' { f e d E J G \ K L { v n C T / h y G c Q N s C C \ = & ` , g G . P - r > F z L s b ( c [ J P { . o T a a / ? h ; W $ h c i m f x , D l _ C % l a L r q ' F m } l c ( V I [ V Y . G H e j K = n p p b v h V ; x - / o z R n ' ; L P W } > y Z = ' - | x u , l z t } | > w k | P , g k U ` F , < g & z c ^ Z s < \ ^ D { | ! C H R y b ` C q I g p $ e S * k e < < q & - A X < b / a K q x q w ) b I ? T h - e ! A . z J p U l } * P G H ! m - F ' = a : B ~ ! . k A " U / Y c b t u } < U K X y H A # { E

How can I fix it?

Comment: Based on your desired output, it seems you just need to remove the second `stable_partition`.

Comment: Can you create a [mre] where it is more obvious how the output of your program is not correct? To me the two outputs look identical and I don't want to compare hundreds of random numbers and letters by eye.

Comment: This is what a debugger i meant for.  Run through the code with a debugger until you find where the code is producing a result that is different than what you are expecting.